# Is there a way to see Sonarwhal testresults or any logging?

Tags: web, accessibility, standards, lint

When I run Sonarwhal (https://sonarwhal.com/docs/user-guide/) on the commandline for a webpage, it generates a list of problems/failures that I should address. Is there any way I can look into these problems? Googled this issue but I cannot find any solution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default "formatter" (how the errors are going to be printed) is "summary". You will have to change it to something else. The list of supported formatters is available in: https://sonarwhal.com/docs/user-guide/concepts/formatters/ with instructions on how to configure them in your .sonarwhalrc file. Basically all you need is add a "formatters" property:

```

```
{
  "extends": ["web-recommended"],
  "formatters": ["codeframe"]
}
```

```

All formatters except "excel" should be in the [web-recommended](https://npmjs.com/package/@sonarwhal/configuration-web-recommended) package.

In the future you can ask questions directly on our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/sonarwhal/sonarwhal).

Comment: Where is the .sonarwhalrc file saved to from a npm -g install?

Comment: I found it ;-) C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sonarwhal\.sonarwhalrc